# Read notebooks programmatically from databricks python notebook

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, databricks

I need programmatically read the content of the specific notebook in my databrick workspace from another notebook in the same workspace.
Following the databricks documentation, I extract the path to my notebook and then list all other notebooks in the directory. This works as expected.

```
notebook_path = os.path.dirname(dbutils.entry_point.getDbutils().notebook().getContext().notebookPath().getOrElse(None))
for f in dbutils.fs.ls(f"file:/Workspace{notebook_path}"):
    print(f)
```

For example:
`FileInfo(path='file:/Workspace/Users/***/Notebook1', name='Notebook1', size=0, modificationTime=0)`

Then I try to read a specific notebook:

```
with open(f"/Workspace{notebook_path}/Notebook1", "r") as _f:
    c = _f.read()
```

I get the following error:

```
OSError: [Errno 95] Operation not supported

File /databricks/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py:282, in _modified_open(file, *args, **kwargs)
    275 if file in {0, 1, 2}:
    276     raise ValueError(
    277         f"IPython won't let you open fd={file} by default "
    278         "as it is likely to crash IPython. If you know what you are doing, "
    279         "you can use builtins' open."
    280     )
--> 282 return io_open(file, *args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: builtins.open doen't work as well - same error appears

Answer (score 0):

I was able to do this by using databricks.sdk.WorkspaceClient. However, it looks like a workaround. I would prefer to read the content of notebooks directly.

```
databricksURL = dbutils.notebook.entry_point.getDbutils().notebook().getContext().apiUrl().getOrElse(None)
myToken = dbutils.notebook.entry_point.getDbutils().notebook().getContext().apiToken().getOrElse(None)
w = WorkspaceClient(host=databricksURL, token=myToken)
export_response = w.workspace.export(path, format=ExportFormat.JUPYTER)
```